# Moto G2 not detected by Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: ubuntu, mtp, motorola-droid

I want to use my Moto G2 for learning app development. I have turned on the debugger and developer settings. It connected to Windows 7 PC of a friend but not with my Ubuntu 14.04. I tried the MTP thing as well, but no use.I went through many solutions about this, saying edit android rules file it didn't help much as I am new to Ubuntu as well. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

So glad that despite being a new bee i found solution.
Got this amazing link:
http://codeyarns.com/2013/12/23/how-to-mount-moto-g-on-ubuntu-using-mtp/

Happy App Developing :)